# MVC3 - CheckBox "id" from entity entry with trailing dot

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox, html-helper

I'm using checkboxes for customers hobbies. I'm creating them with a List of Tuples.

```
List<Tuple<int, string, bool>> hobbies = new List<Tuple<int, string, bool>>();
```

The int is the ID, the string is the name and the bool is true if checked. So far so good. I'm displaying the hobbies with

```
<td>
    @Html.CheckBox(Constants.HobbyPrefix + item.Item2, item.Item3)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item2)
</td>
```

Still ok. HTML code looks like

```
<input id="Hobby_Camping" name="Hobby_Camping" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Hobby_Camping" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

But the code created isn't ok if the string ends with a dot ("."). Let's say a string of a hobby would be "watersp." or any abbreviation. Then the HTML code does not have the trailing dot inside the id- and name-tags. Like

```
<input id="Hobby_Watersp" name="Hobby_Watersp" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Hobby_Watersp" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

Is this fixable? Why is the dot missing? The way to fix it inside the controller is not really acceptable for me. And I don't want to write my own Html-Helper, since I don't know if a trailing dot violates some conventions or specifications.

Thanks in advance.